# THe correct way to install wordpress on ec2 instance Amazon like BiTnami package

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, configuration, bitnami

I've searched and tested multi-tutoriels about installing wordpresson ec2 instance in amazon AWS, but i always find problems with the final product, first MySQL it does not accept utf8_unicode_ci, than the sample data (.xml files) i upload them but dont extract instead the files goes to media as (sampledata.xml_.txt) !!!

So i am hoping to find a solution here to install wordpress the correct way like the package of Bitnami that worked perfectly with no problems but the fees are to much for me so i prefer to do it automaticly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What fees? :) You can launch the Bitnami AMIs for free directly [from your account](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/cloud/amazon) or from the [AWS marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile/ref=srh_res_product_vendor?ie=UTF8&id=dbe6480c-fd0d-4625-9bd0-44606ed33fa6)